# Make turtles finish between 2 elements in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to NetLogo and I'm trying to simulate that a set of turtles have to go from a random space to place themselves between the goal spot and the wall, but so far I've just retrieved part of a code to make them place themselves in all directions around that goal spot (turtles have the ability to speak among themselves).

However, I'm unable to make them finish towards one of the sides... Any hint?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "between the goal spot and the wall" in the context of your first image? I assume the wall is the top blue line, but where is the goal spot, and where do you want the turtle to go?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Luke! The goal spot would be the green patch in the first image, so turtles would be placed randomly around max-pxcor and max-pycor and the objective is that they move towards a "safety area", which in this case would be between the top blue line (wall) and the "goal spot" (green patch), which in my simulation would represent the point from which they are marked as "safe" (think of it as an emergency exit they have to queue to get out). The issue now is that less than half of all turtles would be marked as safe. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if you're still wanting to get them to cluster around the goal-point, or just move above it. Here's one way that may get what you're after. It defines a goal spot and a group of safe patches. Turtles below the goal spot try to move through the goal spot to get to the safe area. More details / explanation in the comments

The setup:

```
globals [ goal-spot safe-patches ]

to setup
  ca
  ;   Set the wall
  ask patches with [ pycor = max-pycor ] [ set pcolor blue ]

  ;  Set the goal-patch
  set goal-spot patch 0 0
  ask goal-spot [ set pcolor green ]

  ;     Set up a triangular safe-patches zone
  let check ( [pycor] of goal-spot - [pxcor] of goal-spot ) - 1
  let gpx [pxcor] of goal-spot
  set safe-patches patches with [
    pycor > [pycor] of goal-spot and
    pycor < max-pycor and
    ( ( pxcor < gpx and pycor + pxcor > check ) or
      ( pxcor >= gpx and pycor - pxcor > check ) ) ]

  ;  Make some turtles
  let n-turtles 255
  if n-turtles > count safe-patches [
    set n-turtles count safe-patches 
  ]
  crt n-turtles [
    set shape "person"
    set color green
    move-to one-of patches with [ pycor < [pycor] of goal-spot and pycor < max-pycor]
    if pycor <= [pycor] of goal-spot [
      set color red
    ]
  ]
  ask turtles [pd]
  reset-ticks
end
```

The movement:

```
to go
  ;   Any turtles that are not on the safe spot, or share a patch
  ask turtles with [not member? patch-here safe-patches or any? other turtles-here] [
    let target nobody

    ;     If below the goal spot, target it. If not, target a free safe patch
    ifelse pycor < [pycor] of goal-spot [
      set target goal-spot
    ] [
      set target min-one-of ( safe-patches with [ 
        not any? other turtles-here ] ) [distance myself
      ]
    ]

    ;     Face target, move to it.
    if target != nobody [
      face target
      move-to patch-ahead 1
    ]
  ]

  ;  Stop when all turtles are safe and on their own patch
  if not any? turtles with [ 
    not member? patch-here safe-patches or
    any? other turtles-here 
  ] [
    stop
  ]

  tick
end
```

Hopefully that gets your started!

Behavior example:

[image]

[image]

**Edit**

As per your comment- yes, you could do something like that. There are certainly many ways to approach this, but the actual implementation will change depending on your actual model and intentions etc. For example, here's a modification that uses two safe zones:

```
globals [ goal-spots safe-patches ]

to setup
  ca

  ;   Set the walls
  ask ( patch-set 
    patches with [ pycor = max-pycor ] 
    patches with [ pxcor = max-pxcor ] 
    )
    [
    set pcolor blue
  ]

  let possible-safe patches with [ pcolor = black ]

  ;     Set up two triangular safe-patches
  crt 1 [
    set heading 0 
    fd 7 
    set goal-spots patch-here
    set safe-patches possible-safe in-cone 20 90
    set heading 90
    setxy 7 0
    set goal-spots ( patch-set goal-spots patch-here )
    set safe-patches ( 
      patch-set 
      safe-patches 
      possible-safe in-cone 20 90 ) 
    die
  ]

  ask safe-patches [
    set pcolor green - 4
  ]

  ;  Make some turtles
  let n-turtles 100
  if n-turtles > count safe-patches [
    set n-turtles count safe-patches
  ]
  crt n-turtles [
    set shape "person"
    set color green
    move-to one-of patches with [ pycor < 0 and pxcor < 0 ]
    set color red
  ]
  ask turtles [pd]

  reset-ticks
end


to go
  ;   Any turtles that are not on the safe spot, or share a patch
  ask turtles with [not member? patch-here safe-patches or any? other turtles-here] [
    let target nobody

    ;     If below the goal spot, target it. If not, target a free safe patch
    ifelse not member? patch-here safe-patches [
      set target min-one-of goal-spots [ distance myself ]
    ] [
      set target min-one-of ( safe-patches with [
        not any? other turtles-here ] ) [distance myself
      ]
    ]

    ;     Face target, move to it.
    if target != nobody [
      face target
      move-to patch-ahead 1
    ]
  ]

  ;  Stop when all turtles are safe and on their own patch
  if not any? turtles with [
    not member? patch-here safe-patches or
    any? other turtles-here
  ] [
    stop
  ]

  tick
end
```

Note that this just a quick example of one approach that has obvious problems (eg. if you have too many turtles on one patch, one or two turtles will get stuck trying to get "in" to the nearest safe zone even when it's full). I would say if you can get your two safe areas defined in some way and then run into problems, it'd be worth posting a new question to figure out how to solve any new issues you come across.

Comment: It definitely gets me started, thanks a lot!! Just one last question, if I had 2 goal patches instead of one (say one with the wall on top and another one with the wall on the right handside) would you do all instructions with the goal-spot twice (like once with goal-spot-1 and another one with goal-spot-2) or is there any other way to do some sort of a "for" loop? (for instance: first setting goal patches in green, then {set goal-spot (patches with [pcolor = green])} and then run the same instructions for patches in goal-spot?).

Comment: @Arduino - I've made a few additions to my answer- have a look!